Tilting complexes arising from homotopy equivalences
Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ and $B$ be finite-dimensional selfinjective $k$-algebras. Suppose we have an isomorphism of homotopy categories $F: K^b(A-mod) \cong K^b(B-mod)$ that descends to a derived equivalence $D^b(A-mod) \cong D^b(B-mod)$. Rickard's theorem asserts the existence of a two-sided tilting complex $T$ inducing the derived equivalence, but Corollary 5.5 of Rickard, Derived equivalences as derived functors also asserts the existence of a homotopy equivalence (in the paper the equivalence is between unbounded homotopy categories, but the complex is bounded, so it also induces an equivalence between bounded homotopy categories). Can one perform or modify this construction so that the corresponding induced equivalence (edit: agrees on objects) with our original equivalence $F$?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "perform this construction". If you mean precisely the construction used in the proof of Corollary 5.5 in that paper, then the answer is no, but if you allow variations of that construction, then maybe.

Also, it's not known that every derived equivalence is induced by a two-sided tilting complex (i.e., is "standard" in the terminology of the same paper).

Indeed, I don't mean performing precisely that construction, but rather, that perhaps there is some variation that obtains a two-sided tilting complex derived equivalent to the two-sided tilting complex arising from the derived equivalence that is naturally isomorphic to the functor $F$.
You are right though, the question I'm posing is too strong. Forgetting naturality, it would be better to only ask if it's possible to perform the construction so that the two-sided tilting complexes agrees on objects with $F$.
